# 10 Rats and 10 bottles, find one non poisonous bottle with least rats killed

Tags: strategy

There are 10 bottles of liquid, out of which 9 bottles are poisonous and one bottle of liquid is non-poisonous. The rats are to be fed this liquid one bottle at a time and rats die instantaneously. The non-poisonous bottle has to be identified with least number of rats killed.

Comment: @bobble rats killed is instantaneously here, shared question has a limit of getting killed

Comment: Are extra victims and/or containers allowed? Does a mixture of poison and non-poison affect the victims differently than pure poison?

Comment: Problem is not actually a puzzle, as the naive solution is correct.

Answer (score 3):

> 10 rats

Because

> Feed a different bottle to each rat. All but one will die. Mark the one that didn't kill a rat as "safe", then feed a different bottle to that rat. Rat problem solved, and you have something to drink.

Answer (score 2):

> 0 rats least (first bottle doesn’t kill rat)

> 9 rats most (first nine bottles kill rat, tenth is non-poison)

Comment: Welcome to PSE! Please hide your answers in spoiler tags; `>!`

Comment: Thank you! That might be the definition of a rookie move!

Comment: Just a note: I didn't receive your message in my inbox as you didn't @myusername. Just thought I'd let you know in case you try to message another user :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> 0 rats

Explanation:

> Feed the liquid to mice until the non-poisonous liquid is found.

Tip:

> Be sure to dispose of the rats, mice and poisonous bottles of liquid before enjoying your drink.